# Using input to find a key in a dictionary and assign the values to that variable

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I currently have this code,

```
  potions ={"small_health":15, "small_instant_exp":250}
  selection = input("Pick one")
```

How would I make it so that selection has the same values as the key that the user picked if they have the same name?

Comment: So if the input is "small_health", then `selection` should be set to 15? Also, what should happen if the input _doesn't_ match anything in the dict?

Comment: It will be in a while loop until the correct choice is selected, but you got the right idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use potions.get() with the input as the paramter

```
potions = {"small_health": 15, "small_instant_exp": 250}
selection = potions.get(input("Pick one"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `try-except` block inside an infinite `while` loop. This keeps on receiving input from user until user enters a correct input (input that matches a key in `potions`).

```
potions = {"small_health": 15,
           "small_instant_exp": 250}

while True:
    try:
        selection = potions[input("Pick one")]
        print(selection)
        break
    except:
        print('Wrong Input')
```